# How to get the exact location from gdb's "info symbol" command

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging, gdbserver

I am debugging with GDB at work. When I input "info symbol 0xABCD", I get the following result,

```
sample_function + 123 in section init
```

I know the EXACT LOCATION is near sample_function(), and have an offset 123, but how do I locate it in the C code? I have not found any resource from internet that talks about this yet. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I locate it in the C code?

You can do:

```
(gdb) disas/m 0xABCD
```

From "help disas":

```
With a /m modifier, source lines are included (if available).
```

Alternatively, this command: `addr2line -fe /path/to/binary 0xABCD` (run outside of GDB) should print source location (if the binary has debug line info).

Comment: Sorry my last comment, disas/m 0xABCD works, thanks. it gives both C and assembly.